# JButton not properly shown in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am making a JFrame menu that has 3 buttons but the buttons aren't shown correctly when started

here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainMenu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nakib Group Managment System");
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton addRequest = new JButton("Add request");
        addRequest.addActionListener(new AddRequest());
        JButton viewRequests = new JButton("View requests");
        viewRequests.addActionListener(new ViewRequests());
        JButton addCab = new JButton("Add a cab");
        addCab.addActionListener(new AddCab());
        panel.add(addRequest);
        panel.add(viewRequests);
        panel.add(addCab);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

When I run this it will show me the following (can't post the image because not enough reputation):
[first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSJEl.jpg)

However, when I resize the window the buttons will show:
[resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdsdZ.jpg)

My OS environment is Windows 10 and I'm working on Java.

Comment: yeah i just noticed and just fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the frame to be visible before adding the components to it, which causes the component hierarchy to be invalid. From [the docs for the add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29):

> If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component.

To correct this, you should move the line `frame.setVisible(true)` to the end, after you add `panel`. Or, alternatively, you can call `revalidate` and `repaint` at the end, to force updating and repainting.

Right now it only works after resizing because that forces it to lay everything out again, and correctly updates the component hierarchy.